# How to return/exchange a purchase made in a Dubai airport terminal?

Tags: dubai, shopping

I had purchased a watch from SWATCH store in Dubai Terminal 2 a couple of weeks ago. I have a flight from Terminal 3 later this week. How can I get from Terminal 3 to Terminal 2 to return/exchange it at the SWATCH store, and get back to Terminal 3 for my onward flight? How long will it take me to go back and forth?

Comment: You probably can't. Contact the company you bought from directly to hear how to make returns/warranty complains on their goods without entering the secure airside area.

Comment: You should probably start by checking with Swatch stores in town. The next possible option is to check if there is a Swatch store in Terminal 3. And the final option is to take the shuttle between Terminals 3 and 2, but the round trip will apparently take you over an hour. Also some airports allow you to move freely between terminals, while others will only allow you to enter a terminal you are actually departing from, I don't know what the policy is at DXB.